How to implement exception handling in a mixed MVC and REST Spring application?
Spring Boot 3.2.x / Spring Web 6.1.x
In an app with both MVC controllers (returning HTML pages via JSP) and REST controllers, how can I implement global exception handling such that MVC controller methods result in an error page while REST endpoints return non-page responses (400, 404, 500, etc with text or JSON response body)?
I have a @ControllerAdvice implemented that handles various kinds of exceptions with specific @ExceptionHandler and @ResponseStatus annotations. These methods all return a page (eg, "forward:/error") as they should for MVC requests.
Here's part of that class:
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {

    //...other methods...

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String defaultInternalErrorHandler(Model model, Exception e, HttpServletRequest req) {
        UUID errorID = UUID.randomUUID();
        log.error(errorID + " | Unhandled exception processing request to " + req.getRequestURI(), e);

        model.addAttribute("exception", e);
        model.addAttribute("errorID", errorID);
        return "forward:/error";
    }

}

This is the "fallback" handler method if none of the others handle the exception that's thrown. This works great for all the MVC controller methods that return pages (HTML).
However, I don't want REST controller endpoints to return HTML content, they should return (JSON in my case) content with an appropriate HTTP response status (eg, 400 for invalid requests, 500 for server errors, etc).
I've tried adding another @RestControllerAdvice class similar to this:
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalRestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ServletRequestBindingException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handle(ServletRequestBindingException e, HttpServletRequest req) {
        defaultInternalErrorHandler(e, req);
        return "Invalid Request: " + e.getMessage();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String defaultInternalErrorHandler(Exception e, HttpServletRequest req) {
        UUID errorID = UUID.randomUUID();
        log.error(errorID + " | Unhandled exception processing API request to " + req.getRequestURI(), e);
        return "Server error: " + e;
    }
}

Unfortunately, that class doesn't seem to be used. Any exception from a REST endpoint is flowing through the @ControllerAdvice default method and returning the error page.
How can I have the best of both worlds, MVC requests going to the error page and REST endpoints returning REST-friendly (JSON) content?

This is supported by the Advice interfaces themselves, and they each provide two means of pulling this off.
You can either differentiate the two by the packages they're in, or by their Controller annotation.
So, if your classes are separated by packages like com.myapp.controller.web and com.myapp.controller.rest you can use @ControllerAdvice("com.myapp.controller.web") and @RestControllerAdvice("com.myapp.controller.rest") respectively.
If you want to let the annotations drive this, you would simply use @ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class) or @RestControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class).
Important Note about using the annotations: Without further guidance, Spring can/will prioritize the @ControllerAdvice annotated handler over the one annotated as @RestControllerAdvice. This is because @RestController is a composite annotation that includes/extends @Controller, so when Spring is testing each advice handler to see if it applies to a given @Controller, it sees even controllers annotated as @RestController as having the @Controller annotation. That means the handler annotated as @ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class) will always apply to REST controllers; if that bean happens to be ordered before the @RestControllerAdvice bean, the REST one will never get a chance to handle exceptions. See the code in org.springframework.web.method.HandlerTypePredicate.test(Class<?> controllerType).
You can work around this by prioritizing the @RestControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.classs handler using @Order annotation (@Priority annotation as well as implementing Ordered interface are also options) so that it has a higher precedence than the default. See this answer for a discussion of the ordering.
Here's an example of a a pair of exception handling advice classes that uses this technique:
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String handle(Model model, Exception e, HttpServletRequest req) {
        UUID errorID = UUID.randomUUID();
        log.error(errorID + " | Unhandled exception processing page request to " + req.getRequestURI(), e);

        model.addAttribute("exception", e);
        model.addAttribute("errorID", errorID);
        return "forward:/error";
    }
}


@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
@Order(0)
public class RESTExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String handle(Exception e, HttpServletRequest req) {
        UUID errorID = UUID.randomUUID();
        log.error(errorID + " | Unhandled exception processing API request to " + req.getRequestURI(), e);

        return "Unhandled exception: " + e;
    }
}


What about the case where a single controller has both MVC and REST endpoints? For example, methods that return a view (String) and others, annotated with @ResponseBody that return objects to be serialized (as JSON, typically).

That's a case for refactoring.  Review the Separation of Concerns and consider separating your API logic from your UI logic

I wouldn't personally build controllers that way, but I've seen it in the wild (including current project). Refactoring controllers isn't always feasible at the moment, so I was wondering if there's any support for it. Still, this is a useful answer and I'll be testing it later today.

Each controller mapping should be able to be isolated.  If they can't be, I'd say that's a smell

After some testing, this isn't as trivial as it seems. I added (annotations = RestController.class) attributes to my @RestControllerAdvice but found that the @ControllerAdvice was still being invoked for the REST endpoints. I ended up having to create a custom annotation, attaching it to my MVC controller, then specifying (annotations = MyMVCController.class) on my @ControllerAdvice. Only then did MVC endpoints use the @ControllerAdvice and REST endpoints use the @RestControllerAdvice.

Hum, I have this in projects and it's working perfectly.  Spring's documentation also states this is correct.  But, if you got it working then you're good to go

I suspect the issue could be due to the fact that @RestController is a composite annotation that includes/extends @Controller. When Spring is told to apply advice based on those 2 annotations, maybe it's detecting that my REST controller is annotated with @Controller and applying the @ControllerAdvice before the @RestControllerAdvice. Just speculating, but I don't have time to investigate any further.

I lied, I did have some time to spend. The code in org.springframework.web.method.HandlerTypePredicate.test(Class<?> controllerType) indeed does find that @Controller on my REST controller, "inherited" through @RestController. That's unfortunate, because it means I'd have to make sure every MVC controller is annotated with my custom annotation.

Applying the @Order annotation (or @Priority if you prefer Jakarta annotations) to the advice class allows me to make the @RestControllerAdvice higher priority (preferred) over the @ControllerAdvice without having to use a custom marker annotation on my MVC controllers. I'll be editing the answer to reflect these findings and provide a more complete solution.
